# Bootstrap 4 tabs (pills) underlined

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want Bootstrap 4 tabs (or pills) to be rendered underline.

Like this:

[image]

Default Bootstrap 4 has no such styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with new class .nav-pills-underline and based on Bootstrap 4 variables.

Change variables accordingly in sass file.

mynavs.scss

```
$nav-pills-underline-link-active-color: $link-color !default;
$nav-pills-underline-link-hover-color: $link-hover-color !default;

$nav-pills-underline-bg:    transparent !default;
$nav-pills-underline-active-bg:    transparent !default;
$nav-pills-underline-hover-bg:    transparent !default;

$nav-pills-underline-border-width:    3px !default;
$nav-pills-underline-border-color:    map-get($theme-colors, "secondary");



.nav-pills-underline{
  .nav-link {
    @include border-radius(0);

    &.active,
    .show > & {
      color: $nav-pills-underline-link-active-color;
      //background-color: $nav-pills-underline-active-bg;

    }
  }

  > li.nav-item {
    > a.nav-link{

      background-color: $nav-pills-underline-bg !important;

      border-bottom-width: $nav-pills-underline-border-width;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }

    > a.nav-link.active,
    > a.nav-link.active:hover,
    > a.nav-link:hover
    {
      text-decoration: none;

      border-bottom-width: $nav-pills-underline-border-width;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: $nav-pills-underline-border-color;
    }

    // bg
    > a.nav-link.active{
      background-color: $nav-pills-underline-active-bg !important;
    }



    // color
    > a.nav-link.active:hover,
    > a.nav-link:hover
    {
      color: $nav-pills-underline-link-hover-color;
      background-color: $nav-pills-underline-hover-bg !important;

    }

  }



}
```

use css class in HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-underline">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Find all files here: https://gist.github.com/maxivak/86535e8e6d3504d62bf7d637bf46109c

Answer (score 0):

css for mutiple tab

```
  .tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    .tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }


    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
    }
```

---

html for tab

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
</div>

<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>tab 1</h3>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>tab 2</h3>
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>tab 3</h3>
</div>
```

---

script for tab

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```